# Parse XML in Windows-1251 encoding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, nokogiri

Trying to run:

```
Nokogiri::XML(open("http://my.url.com/any/path.xml"))
```

For example:

```
Nokogiri::XML(open("http://bar-navig.yandex.ru/u?ver=2&show=32&url=google.com"))
```

But I get:

> Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Unsupported encoding windows-1251

But only on the server. On the local computer it works fine.

It looks like iconv supports this encoding:

```
iconv --list | grep 1251
CP1251 MS-CYRL WINDOWS-1251
```

And even if I try to run in bash

```
xmllint 'http://bar-navig.yandex.ru/u?ver=2&show=32&url=google.com'
```

It works fine.

Ruby 1.9.3
Rails 3.2.16
nokogiri 1.6.1
OS: FreeBSD 8.1

Here sample of code, on line 16.
https://github.com/anoam/seo_params/blob/master/lib/seo_params/yandex.rb

And this is sample of URL:
http://bar-navig.yandex.ru/u?ver=2&show=32&url=google.com

How can I solve it?

Comment: What version of Ruby do you use on the server?

Comment: We need to see a minimal sample of your code and input data that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3
Rails 3.2.16
nokogiri 1.6.1
OS: FreeBSD 8.1

I'll add sample of code to OP in few minutes.

Comment: Please do not link to your code. *WHEN* that link dies your question will make no sense. SO prefers seeing a minimal sample that demonstrates the problem. Asking us to chase down your code discourages potential answers.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand what is the problem. There is simplest example of problem code in original post.
> Nokogiri::XML(open("http://my.url.com/any/path.xml"))
Instead "http://my.url.com/any/path.xml" I have tried different urls, for example "http://bar-navig.yandex.ru/u?ver=2&show=32&url=google.com".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved here:
https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1093

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

`Nokogiri::XML` is a shortcut for `Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse()`, so look at the documentation for [`Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse()`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-c-parse)

```
parse(string_or_io, url = nil, encoding = nil, options = ParseOptions::DEFAULT_XML, &block)
```

> encoding (optional) is the encoding that should be used when processing the document.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. But I have tried to set encoding in parameters. But result is same:

> Nokogiri::XML(open("http://bar-navig.yandex.ru/u?ver=2&show=32&url=google.com"), nil, 'windows1251')
> Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Unsupported encoding windows-1251